# How to display hh:mm:ss in NSTimer?

Tags: ios, timer, nstimer

Hello I'm trying to make a simple countdown app.

However my countdown is only in seconds and not in minutes and hours. How do I make it such?

Comment: you want to display seconds only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the timer:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(Countdown) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
```

Countdown method:

```
-(void) Countdown {
    int hours, minutes, seconds;

    secondsLeft--;
    hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
    minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
    seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
}
```

Reference :  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html

Comment: That works perfectly thank you! How would I go about hiding something if it's = 0? e.g. if I set to 5 mins how do I hide the hours part of it?

Comment: Also what difference does it make if I have %02d vs %d, what does the 02 do?

Comment: have a look at this link u might get a handful of knowledge  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some logic, to convert seconds to minutes, hours.

Lets say :

`s` Seconds.

```
h = s/3600;
m = s/60-h*60;
s = s%60;
NSString *clockTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld:%02ld",h,m,s];
```

Then you can form a string with your desired `hh:mm:ss`

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your Answer:-**

```
- (void)displayLabel:(UILabel *)lbl timerInterval:(NSTimeInterval)timerInterval {
 uint seconds = fabs(timerInterval); 
 uint minutes = seconds / 60;
 uint hours = minutes / 60;
 seconds -= minutes * 60;
 minutes -= hours * 60;

 lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%02uh:%02um:%02us", (timerInterval<0?@"-":@""),         hours, minutes, seconds];
}
```